# Is there a generic way of converting PCollection to PTable in Apache Crunch?

Tags: apache-crunch

I have these method in a util class which are converting specific PCollection to specific PTable.

```
public static PTable<IdDetails, CASegmentsForModification> getPTableForCASegments(PCollection<CASegmentsForModification> aggregatedPCollectionForCASegments) {
    return aggregatedPCollectionForCASegments.parallelDo(new CASegmentsPTableConverter(),
            Avros.tableOf(Avros.records(IdDetails.class), Avros.records(CASegmentsForModification.class)));
}

public static PTable<IdDetails, UserPrimaryIdMapping> getPTableForPrimaryIdMapping(PCollection<UserPrimaryIdMapping> pCollectionOfUserPrimaryIdMapping) {
    return pCollectionOfUserPrimaryIdMapping.parallelDo(new UserPrimaryIdMappingPTableConverter(),
            Avros.tableOf(Avros.records(IdDetails.class), Avros.records(UserPrimaryIdMapping.class)));
}

public static PTable<IdDetails, UserGroupSegments> getPTableForUserGroupSegments(PCollection<UserGroupSegments> pCollectionOfUserGroupSegments) {
    return pCollectionOfUserGroupSegments.parallelDo(new UserGroupSegmentsPTableConverter(),
            Avros.tableOf(Avros.records(IdDetails.class), Avros.records(UserGroupSegments.class)));
}
```

How can I implement one generic method of above methods ?

Answer (score 2):

There is a better way using static [asPtable](https://crunch.apache.org/apidocs/0.15.0/org/apache/crunch/lib/PTables.html#asPTable-org.apache.crunch.PCollection-) method from the PTables util class. Your PCollection has to be of the type Pair and the PTable result will be of the type PTable

```
    public static <K,V> PTable<K,V> asPTable(PCollection<Pair<K,V>> pcollect)
```

Based on your example you just need to create your DoFn (or extended classes) yo return a Avros.pairs(Avros.records(yourClass.class), Avros.records(yourOtherClass.class)).

Another way is use a predefined MapFn which is [ExtractKEyFn](https://crunch.apache.org/apidocs/0.15.0/org/apache/crunch/fn/ExtractKeyFn.html) and apply it over your collection. You will need to implement the map method to extract the key and generate the key,value output. It is essentially the same idea, after that you can convert the PCollection> into the the PTable

It should save you a lot of boilerplate code.

Just in case, there are other functions which could be useful like [FilterFn](https://crunch.apache.org/apidocs/0.15.0/org/apache/crunch/FilterFn.html) however we found some bugs when you use [MemPipeline](https://crunch.apache.org/apidocs/0.15.0/org/apache/crunch/impl/mem/MemPipeline.html) for unit testing. The first approach that I suggested should be most safe.

EDIT:

A good balance to save some code would be get your key based on a field name using the field name and call this MapFn for each PCollection.

```
//we are assuming the key will be in the first level of your record
public class GenericRecordToPair <V extends GenericRecord, K extends GenericRecord> extends MapFn<V, Pair<K, V>> {
    String key;

    public GenericRecordToPair(String key){
        this.key = key;
    }

    @Override
    public Pair<T, TupleN> map(S input) {
        return new Pair<K,V> (input.get(key), input);
    }

}
```

From your example you could do something like

```
PCollection<UserGroupSegments> pCollectionOfUserGroupSegments = ...//comming from somewhere
PCollection<UserPrimaryIdMapping> pCollectionOfUserPrimaryIdMapping = ...//comming from somewhere
PTable<IdDetails, UserGroupSegments> pTable1 = PTables.asPTable(pCollectionOfUserGroupSegments.parallelDo(new GenericRecordToPair("idDetails"), Avros.pairs(Avros.records(IdDetails.class), Avros.records(UserGroupSegments))));
PTable<IdDetails, UserPrimaryIdMapping> pTable2 = PTables.asPTable(pCollectionOfUserPrimaryIdMapping.parallelDo(new GenericRecordToPair("idDetails"), Avros.pairs(Avros.records(IdDetails.class), Avros.records(UserPrimaryIdMapping))));
```

Comment: But my PCollection is not of Pair<K, V>, its only of V ....... to use method "asPTable" , I need to first convert my PCollection<V> to PCollection<K, V> which also leads to redundant code .
for example I can use this generic method to read and get a PCollection of some avro :-
public static  <T extends SpecificRecord> PCollection<T> getPCollection(Pipeline pipeline, String path, Class<T> clazz) {
        return pipeline.read(From.avroFile(path, clazz));
 }

Comment: what about  use the ExtractKeyFn over your PCollection<V> ? you will always need to provide a way how you want to extract the key from your class, even if you create a generate Function to use genericRecords and extract the key based in a field name, there is no way to generate a key,value without logic to extract the key

Comment: In a same way, is it possible to write one generic method for above use case

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly the purpose of the [`PCollection.by`](http://crunch.apache.org/apidocs/0.15.0/org/apache/crunch/PCollection.html#by-org.apache.crunch.MapFn-org.apache.crunch.types.PType-) method, which accepts a MapFn to generate the key and returns a PTable with each record keyed by the result of that MapFn.

So you could do something like:

```
PTable<IdDetails, CASegmentsForModification> pTableForCASegments = aggregatedPCollectionForCASegments.by(
    new CASegmentsKeyMapFn(),
    Avros.records(IdDetails.class)
)
```